# Display only comment form in a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, comments

I'm trying to display a comment form in a "Golden Book" page.
I have use php to do that, using "Insert PhP" plugin and it's working well.

My problem is that the comments appears on top of the form making it going down in the page as the comments appear.

Do you know how could I display only the form ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you want to remove users comment?

Comment: I wan't them not to appear, just the form. I used <?php comment_form(); ?>